# Concatenate strings in bash

Tags: bash

I have in a bash script:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`
do
   read AA BB CC <<< $(cat file1 |  grep DATA)
   echo ${i}
   echo ${CC}
   SORT=${CC}${i}
   echo ${SORT}
done
```

so "i" is a integer, and CC is a string like "TODAY"

I would like to get then in `SORT`, "TODAY1", etc

But I get "1ODAY", "2ODAY" and so

Where is the error?

Thanks

Comment: The command `for i in \`seq 1 10\` ; do echo HELLO$i ; done` gives HELLO1 HELLO2 ... The problem may be in file1

Comment: show an example of your contents of your input file1, and your desired output.

Answer (score 7):

You should try

```
SORT="${CC}${i}"
```

Make sure your file does not contain "\r" that would end just in the end of $CC.
This could well explain why you get "1ODAY".

Try including
  |tr '\r' ''
after the cat command

Comment: your files may have \r\n lien ending, and read understands only the \n. So the \r ends in the CC variable...you should remove it.

Comment: +1 Had a related problem reading a curl header into a variable

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   for i in {1..10}
    do
      while read -r line
      do
        case "$line" in
         *DATA* ) 
             set -- $line
             CC=$3
             SORT=${CC}${i}
             echo ${SORT}
        esac
      done <"file1" 
    done
```

Otherwise, show an example of file1 and your desired output

Answer (score 1):

ghostdog is right: with the -r option, read avoids succumbing to potential horrors, like CRLFs.  Using arrays makes the -r option more pleasant:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`
do
   read -ra line <<< $(cat file1 |  grep DATA)
   CC="${line[3]}"
   echo ${i}
   echo ${CC}
   SORT=${CC}${i}
   echo ${SORT}
done
```